# In Perl, how can I skip some rows returned from a DBI select using multiple regex matches?

Tags: regex, perl

When I write out a [`HTML::Table`](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML%3a%3aTable) I want to skip certain rows. This should be done according to a few user parameters which I get from the web page and compile them as regex.

The Parameters are the upper case `NOT_*` with values such as `cc08` or a post code or whatever.

```
my $nameRegex =    ($NOT_NAME)  ? qr/$NOT_NAME/  : '';
my $rackRegex =    ($NOT_RACK)  ? qr/$NOT_RACK/  : '';
my $unitRegex =    ($NOT_UNIT)  ? qr/$NOT_UNIT/  : '';
my $addressRegex = ($NOT_ADDR)  ? qr/$NOT_ADDR/  : ''; 
my $townRegex  =   ($NOT_TOWN)  ? qr/$NOT_TOWN/  : '';
my $pcodeRegex =   ($NOT_PCODE) ? qr/$NOT_PCODE/ : '';
```

In the while loop (for a SQL query elsewhere) I get the data, and what I think im doing is "unless you match any of these" add this row of results.

```
while ((my $id, my $name, my $rack, my $unit, my $town, my $address, my $pcode, my $lat, my $lon) = $select_sites->fetchrow_array()) {
        my $checkbox = "<input type='checkbox' name='FILTER_SITE' value='$id' $checked{$id} />";

        unless ($name =~ $nameRegex
            || $rack =~ $rackRegex
            || $unit =~ $unitRegex
            || $address =~ $addressRegex
            || $town =~ $townRegex 
            || $pcode =~ $pcodeRegex) {

            $rows++;
            $sitesResultSection->addRow($checkbox, $name, $rack, $unit, $town, $address, $pcode, $lat, $lon);
        }
```

Spitting the Regexs  would look something like this for `$NOT_RACK = "cc08"`

```
  = qr//;
 (?-xism:cc08) = qr/cc08/;
  = qr//;
  = qr//; 
   = qr//;
  = qr//;
```

However the problem is no rows are added at all, while only one result in the query must be omitted for "cc08", and all others must be shown.

The reason I'm doing this in HTML is because there are already other filters in the SQL query (limiting the result set significantly) and making those filters dynamic according to user input would be a nightmare.

**Answer accepted, however I had a further issue:**

This is how I initialised those NOT_s, in the same fashion I used for my query's `REGEXP` conditions. Thusly when a user enters "City rackname" it'll display racks in `City`

```
my $NOT_NAME = &useOrs(&trim($cgi->param('NOT_NAME')));
my $NOT_RACK = &useOrs(&trim($cgi->param('NOT_RACK')));
my $NOT_UNIT = &useOrs(&trim($cgi->param('NOT_UNIT')));
my $NOT_ADDR = &useOrs(&trim($cgi->param('NOT_ADDR')));
my $NOT_TOWN = &useOrs(&trim($cgi->param('NOT_TOWN')));
my $NOT_PCODE= &useOrs(&trim($cgi->param('NOT_PCODE')));

my $QUICK_SEARCH_SITES = &trim($cgi->param('QUICK_SEARCH_SITES'));
my $searchRegexp = ($QUICK_SEARCH_SITES) ? &useOrs($QUICK_SEARCH_SITES) : '.*';

sub useOrs {
    my $tmp = $_[0];
    $tmp =~ s/\s+/|/g;
    return $tmp;
}
```

Here's an excerpt from the SQL query `WHERE name REGEXP ? OR rack-id REGEXP ? OR [..]`
So with these hacks some reasonable flexibility is achieved without having to train the monkeys that will use the tool. 
However using merely `$var =~ /$NOT_VAR/` will apparently match only exactly that, case sensitive etc.
To achieve the looseness of the SQL filter Instead of using `&useOrs` I use

```
sub useAny {
    my $tmp = $_[0];
    $tmp =~ s/\s/./g;
    return $tmp;
}
```

And most importantly `$var =~ /.*$NOT_VAR.*/i`

I was under the impression that one is supposed to hack away with Perl so there.. :) Suggestions still welcome.

Comment: If you have a separate question, post a separate question. *one is supposed to hack away with Perl* does not reflect well. Whatever the programming language, throwing stuff on the wall until it sticks for a while is not the right approach.

Comment: I don't I just expanded my post because I found a further issue with my code. And hacking's supposed to be solving problems right? I find my present accepted solution appropriately robust and readable.

Comment: `/.* ... .*/` is default behaviour for perl regexes, and you do not need to add it. `/$NOT_VAR/` matches exactly the same things as `/.*$NOT_VAR.*/`, it only matters if you are capturing anything, or are using the `/g` option. Which you are not.

Comment: Yes, the `/i` was the important bit in that modification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

As Sinan Ünür has pointed out, there is a hidden functionality, described in [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators) in that any empty regex `//` will instead use the last successfully matched regex. A very strange feature, IMO, and in this case will cause subtle errors.

That makes it a bad idea to use variables inside regexes, unless they are checked for content first.

**Solution:**

What you *should* do, IMO, is exchange this for a subroutine, e.g.:

```
sub check_var {
    my ($var, $NOT_VAR) = @_;
    return 0 unless $NOT_VAR;
    return ($var =~ /$NOT_VAR/);
}
```

And then use it as such:

```
unless ( check_var($name, $NOT_NAME) 
      || check_var($rack, $NOT_RACK)
      ....
```

Comment: Well, now all results are displayed and it's as if the NOT's are not applied at all

Comment: @Recc It would help immensely if you would speak in terms of the if-condition here. When you say "all results are displayed", I have to go check your code. I assume you mean that whatever is inside the `unless` block is executed. This means that at least one of the `check_var` calls returned true for all rows. So you need to figure out why, and the best way to do that is to make use of the Data::Dumper module to see what's inside your data. Try `$Data::Dumper::Useqq=1; print Dumper $NOT_NAME;` etc. Remember that whitespace counts as "true".

Comment: Indeed, though nothing more was happening to the variables, It was something else which I overlooked, my eyes smeared by the difference between MySQLs handling of regex and Perl's and my preprocessing of the input I will clarify in my answer, as though the issue was deeper the empty `//` was the first wall. This answer is most suitable and works great now.

Answer (score 4):

From [perldoc perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html):

> The empty pattern `//`
>
> If the PATTERN evaluates to the empty string, the last
>       *successfully* matched regular expression is used instead. In
>       this case, only the "g" and "c" flags on the empty pattern are
>       honored; the other flags are taken from the original pattern. If
>       no match has previously succeeded, this will (silently) act
>       instead as a genuine empty pattern (which will always match).

So, you can make your life easier by using:

```
my $nameRegex = qr/$NOT_NAME/;
my $rackRegex = qr/$NOT_RACK/;
my $unitRegex = qr/$NOT_UNIT/;
my $addressRegex = qr/$NOT_ADDR/; 
my $townRegex  = qr/$NOT_TOWN/;
my $pcodeRegex = qr/$NOT_PCODE/;
```

Or, better, use hashes (**code is not tested**):

```
use List::MoreUtils qw( any );

my %patterns = (
    name => qr/$NOT_NAME/,
    rack => qr/$NOT_RACK/,
    unit => qr/$NOT_UNIT/,
    address => qr/$NOT_ADDR/,
    town => qr/$NOT_TOWN/,
    pcode => qr/$NOT_PCODE/,
);

while (my $row = $select_sites->fetchrow_hashref("NAME_lc")) {
    my $checkbox = '...';

    next if any { $row->{$_} =~ $patterns{$_} } keys %patterns;

    $rows++;
    $sitesResultSection->addRow(
        $checkbox,
        @{ $row }{qw(name rack unit town address pcode lat lon)}
    }
}
```

This assumes the column names match the variable names you used.

Finally, are you using a `where` clause in your SQL `select`? It would be far better to specify, if you can, which rows should be excluded before you fetch the data.

For example, `select name, rack, unit, address, town, pcode lat lon from TABLE where rack <> 'cc08' and town <> 'Concord'` or something along those lines.

Comment: +1 It seems to be true that `//` uses the last successful regex used, even when the variables are not the same. I've never heard of that before, and it seems a bit odd... a source for many weird and hard to find bugs.

Comment: +1 for hashed dispatch.  I sometimes also see people somewhat dangerously constructing an überpattern: `$r = join '|' => grep { length } @runtime_patterns; qr/$r/ if $r`.  FWIW, `any()` from [List::MoreUtils](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List::MoreUtils) might be a skosh more efficient than the scalar grep.

Comment: @pilcrow Thanks for suggesting `any`. I forgot. More importantly than the efficiency, it makes the line more expressive.

Comment: This is cool, but overkill and with `fetchrow_hashref` tricky for my system will almost certainly change DB and script-side many times